# Call Jenkins file pipeline within another jenkins file pipeline

Tags: jenkins, pipeline

I merged serveral git repositories to one. Now all my eclipse plugin projects are located in one repository. Former each repo was its own build job with its own jenkins file. This jenkins file declared a pipeline. Then the main build job called the other jenkins build jobs. The project directory structure is as follow:

```
RootDir(Git Repo)
--|-> ProjectA-Dir
-------|-> jenkinsfile => contains a pipeline
--|-> ProjectB-Dir
-------|-> jenkinsfile => contains a pipeline
--main_jenkinsfile => File with main pipeline
```

Now I want to call each jenkinsfile pipeline within the main_jekinsfile

For example:

RootDir/main_jenkinsfile

```
pipeline{
stage ('Build ProjectA') {
// execute jenkinsfile from ProjectA-Dir
}
stage ('Build ProjectB') {
// execute jenkinsfile from ProjectB-Dir
}
}
```

But didn't find any code what can execute jenkins file from a sub directory.